# Mongoose findOne always retrieves the first document in my collection

Tags: node.js, express, sencha-touch-2, mongoose

I have a sencha touch client and a REST API written in node and express, this API has a login method that looks like this:

```
exports.loginUser = function(req, res){
  User.findOne ({email: req.params.email, password: req.params.password}, function(err, user){
    if (!err){
        res.send(user);
    }

    res.send(err);
  });
};
```

I'm totally sure that my sencha touch client is sending the login credentials I'm attempting to query to my server side application. The problem is that the findOne method always returns the first document of my user collection. I executed the same query in mongo shell and it returned the right document, I don't understand why am I getting the same result no matter what credentials I send to node. Here's the data I'm posting from my client:

```
var values = this.getLogin().getValues(),
    user = Ext.create('app.model.User',{
     email: values.txtemail,
     password: values.txtpass
    });

    Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/login/',
      params: user,

      success: function(response){
         console.log(response);
      }

    });
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure your req.params.email and req.params.password are correct. You can also try giving hardcoded email and password for testing. Otherwise everything looks fine.

Comment: do a `console.log(req.params)` on server and see what gets passed to the server?

Comment: Hi. Yeah, I figured out my params are undefined. I don't know why though, ig I console.log the data that comes out of my Sencha app everything seems to be ok. It seems the Sencha model giving me trouble, so I0m going to remove it and try again.